# PHP - how to sort xml item with predefined date (pubDate)

Tags: php, xml

In my PHP script, i want to check in any xml file, if any new item is published since my last checkout.
Currently, i use a foreach and a if, but i don't want to read all the xml file because i have a lot of file to check.

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $item){
    if (strtotime($item->pubDate) > $myTimestamp){
        // new item
    }
}
```

If possible, i want to use something like a while loop for ignore oldest item.

Thanks for helping a french man !